# How to remove "Open menu"

Tags: firefox, user-interface

I am using Firefox 29. I would like to remove this menu because I prefer the
Menu Bar. How can I do this?

> [image: open]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The manual way

I'm listing this first as it's the most efficient way.

1. Close Firefox.
2. Add the following code to your `userChrome.css` file:

   ```css
   #PanelUI-menu-button
   {
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```

   It is located in the `chrome` subfolder inside your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox). Create one in case it doesn't exists already. Here's an example: [userChrome-example.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome-example.css).

   **Note** Apparently `!important` doesn't seem to be needed and could be omitted.
3. Start Firefox again.

### Userstyle

If you have the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on installed, you can use this: [Hide #PanelUI-menu-button for firefox v29+](http://userstyles.org/styles/101114/hide-panelui-menu-button-for-firefox-v29).

Comment: Great answer. Also it makes sense that `!important` is optional as I suspect you would rarely have competing chrome CSS definitions.

Comment: Since there was no such, I have created "userChrome.css" (with content as you wrote) inside a newly created "Chrome" folder. Then I have copied this "Chrome" folder to these two locations: - C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
- C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles There was no other "Profiles" folder on the whole C:\ but the "menu button" is still there. Do you have some idea what is the problem?

Comment: @user321719 The Firefox profile folder is usually stored in the following location in Windows Vista and later: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profileFolder>`. To make things easier, press Win+R, type or paste `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` in the text box, and press Enter. You should see all Firefox profile folders (there's only one by default). Open the folder, and put the `chrome` folder there. Assuming you did it right, the changes should be applied next time you start Firefox.

Comment: Since Firefox 69, there is a prerequisite: `userChrome.css` needs to be enabled in about:config, see [Firefox 69: userChrome.css and userContent.css disabled by default - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/).